# Compiling C/C++ source code on Linux for different platforms

Tags: c++, linux, windows, operating-system, cross-compiling

I have already read something about compiling C/C++ source codes on Linux for running them on Windows. I also tried this with MinGW and everything worked fine.

However, I do not understand why I have to use MinGW on Linux for making binaries that work on Windows. What makes g++ outputs impossible to run on Windows? Also what makes g++ outputs possible to run them on Linux? Does the output file have a different structure: header, data etc and they can be interpreted only by a specific operating system?

Can anyone make it clear for me? I would appreciate if any of you would explain me this not only as for amateur but also as for a person who is interested in operating systems and would like to know what is the real point behind this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats - each OS family has its own, more or less.

Comment: `Does the output file have a different structure: header, data etc and they can be interpreted only by a specific operating system?` Yes. And, the available environment and libraries are completely different too (eg. what needs to be executed when the program starts, etc.etc.etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [x86 Linux versus Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390331/x86-linux-versus-windows)

Comment: There doesn't exist any language called C/C++.

Comment: Where exactly do you expect your Linux system to have all the MS Windows libraries that any executable running on MS Windows must be linked with? They're not going to appear on your Linux system out of thin air. That's what MinGW installs.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Gave most on point answer. manni66 you are very clever, it does not exist! ;). deviantfan Thanks as well

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you tell me what is concretely meant by MS Windows libraries? The libraries like stdio.h etc? They are programmed differently on Linux and on Windows, right?

Comment: @scarface: Indeed. `stdio` will call `write()` on Linux, but `WriteFile` on Windows.

Comment: `stdio.h` is not a library. It is a header file, but the same principle applies: do you actually believe that `stdio.h` on Linux and Windows is completely identical, and in fact it's completely identical on every operating system in the world? Of course not. If you intend to write software for different operating systems, I think it would be useful for you to spend some time studying the basic principles of operating system design and implementation. At least something like that was taught back when I was in college.

Comment: "What makes g++ outputs impossible to run on Windows?" - flawed assumption. Windows 10 _can_ run them. Install "Ubuntu Bash" for Windows, and you can.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik are you telling us that if we write C code and include stdio.h and compile this for different platforms (Win, Lin, Mac) that we are including different files depending on the target?

Comment: This depends entirely on the compiler and the build environment. Some compilers will have a single header file that checks predefined macros set by the compiler that indicates the target platform, and provide the platform-specific definitions. Other compilers will have different header files in different directories, for each target platform, and use a different header file search path depending on the target. But, unlike the question was asking, you can't simply run the standard `g++` on Linux, as is, get an executable, and expect it to run on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Building binaries on Linux for Windows amounts to cross-compiling, in the same sense that building binaries on Linux for, say, Android does. The Windows and Linux machines may (perhaps) have similar hardware, but they are very different operating platforms.

What happens at the platform level when you execute something even as simple as `prinf("Hello world")` differs between platforms. That is, the way that characters are presented to a console is different. There are even greater challenges when it comes to calls like `fork()`, which don't really correspond to anything that Windows process management does.

I believe that even the way that program code and data is loaded into memory is different between Windows and Linux, even on the same hardware.

There's simply no particular reason to think that a native binary built for one platform will run on another. With Java, we've kind of gotten used to the idea that compiled code is cross-platform, but what goes in a Java .class file isn't native executable code -- we rely on the Java run-time system to do the right thing at the platform level. With C/C++, we need the build tools to do that (and very often some measure of programmer expertise as well).